# Reactive not working with dropdown dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive, ggraph

I have two ggraph plots - graph1 and graph2 and I want graph1 to be shown when the dropdown item "1" is chosen and graph2 to be shown when the dropdown item "2" is being chosen. But, reactive is not displaying any of the plots on the chosen values. I'm using the following code snippet in **server.UI**

```
shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

    inData <- reactive({
        if ("1" %in% input$in) return(graph1)
        if ( "2" %in% input$in) return(graph2)
        })
    output$plot <- renderPlot(
        inData)
})
```

Here is the **UI.R file**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Test"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("in", 'Choose', choices = list("1","2"))),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
))
```

If I directly put

```
output$plot <- graph1
```

The graph1 is displayed correctly.

I think there is some problem here ??

```
if ("1" %in% input$in) return(graph1)
if ( "2" %in% input$in) return(graph2)
```

Comment: The parentheses: `inData()`.

Comment: Wow! It worked like a charm! Thank you so much @StéphaneLaurent